# Application Insights - Application map missing incoming request node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, wcf, azure-application-insights

I have MVC.Net application which has it's own application insights configure and this application makes a call to WCF service(using service reference client) and the WCF service also have application insights configured. 
What I'm looking for here, in WCF application insights I want to see mvc application insights component as an incoming request (Initial request) node to WCF service application insights node. Just for the information, I have installed Application Insights WCF SDK package.

[Expected view application map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlwHu.png)

Firstly want to know, is this even possible and if yes, then any tips or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WCF doesn't play nicely with restoring correlation context.

Here is a github issue which tracks it for outgoing calls: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1631.

You might need to do something similar (to workaround in above github issue) for incoming requests - read headers and initialize the right Activity class.

Comment: HttpContext.Current is always null.